# Need help for a game, php form and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have many problems with a form that I have to create...

```
<form  method="post" action="target.php" id="myForm">
    <span class="form_col">Name</span>
    <input />
    <br /><br />

    <span class="form_col">Gender :</span>
    <label><input name="sex" type="radio" value="H" />Male</label>
    <label><input name="sex" type="radio" value="F" />Female</label>
    <br /><br />

    <label class="form_col">Race :</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="Human" />Human</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="Elf" />Elf</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="Orc" />Orc</label>
    <br /><br />

    <label class="form_col">Primary color :</label>
    <select name="prcolor" id="prcolor">
        <option value="none">Select the primary color</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />

    <label class="form_col" for="firstName">Body color :</label>
    <select name="bcolor" id="bcolor">
        <option value="base">Base</option>
        <option value="redb">Red</option>
        <option value="brownb">Brown</option>
        <option value="blackb">Black</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />

    <label class="form_col">Hair color :</label>
    <select name="hair" id="hair">
        <option value="none">Select the color</option>
        <option value="blackh">Black</option>
        <option value="greyh">Grey</option>
        <option value="brownh">Brown</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />

    <span class="form_col">Weapon :</span>
    <label><input type="radio" value="sword" />Sword</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="shield" />Shield</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="knife" />Knife</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="wand" />Wand</label>
    <br /><br />

    <span class="form_col">Clothes :</span>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="armor" />Armor</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="coat" />coat</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="dress" />Dress</label>
    <br /><br />

    <span class="form_col">Accessory :</span>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="hat" />Hat</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="helmet" />Helmet</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="glasses" />Glasses</label>
    <br /><br />

    <span class="form_col">Pet :</span>
    <label><input name="sex" type="radio" value="mount" />Mount</label>
    <label><input name="sex" type="radio" value="pet" />Pet</label>
    <label><input name="sex" type="radio" value="none" />None</label>
    <br /><br />

    <span class="form_col"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I need to send these informations to a database, but i don't know how to do...
And on mysql i don't know which type i need to use for each information...

Anyone can help me to make this form functional ?
Actually i really don't know how to do, I did some research but no results..

Thanks in advance

Comment: google php pdo mysql insert

Comment: Try learning php. Get a good book.

Comment: For your next questions please, go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) then read  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask a Question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a good, well formed and on-topic question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You php form page.

```
<form  method="post" action="target.php" id="myForm">
<span class="form_col">Name</span>
<input />
<br /><br />

<span class="form_col">Gender :</span>
<label><input name="sex" type="radio" value="H" />Male</label>
<label><input name="sex" type="radio" value="F" />Female</label>
<br /><br />

<label class="form_col">Race :</label>
<label><input name="race" type="radio" value="Human" />Human</label>
<label><input name="race" type="radio" value="Elf" />Elf</label>
<label><input name="sex" type="radio" value="Orc" />Orc</label>
<br /><br />

<label class="form_col">Primary color :</label>
<select name="prcolor" id="prcolor">
    <option value="none">Select the primary color</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
<br /><br />

<label class="form_col" for="firstName">Body color :</label>
<select name="bcolor" id="bcolor">
    <option value="base">Base</option>
    <option value="redb">Red</option>
    <option value="brownb">Brown</option>
    <option value="blackb">Black</option>
</select>
<br /><br />

<label class="form_col">Hair color :</label>
<select name="hair" id="hair">
    <option value="none">Select the color</option>
    <option value="blackh">Black</option>
    <option value="greyh">Grey</option>
    <option value="brownh">Brown</option>
</select>
<br /><br />

<span class="form_col">Weapon :</span>
<label><input name="weapon" type="radio" value="sword" />Sword</label>
<label><input name="weapon" type="radio" value="shield" />Shield</label>
<label><input name="weapon" type="radio" value="knife" />Knife</label>
<label><input name="weapon" type="radio" value="wand" />Wand</label>
<br /><br />

<span class="form_col">Clothes :</span>
<label><input name="clothes" type="checkbox" value="armor" />Armor</label>
<label><input name="clothes" type="checkbox" value="coat" />coat</label>
<label><input name="clothes" type="checkbox" value="dress" />Dress</label>
<br /><br />

<span class="form_col">Accessory :</span>
<label><input name="Acc" type="checkbox" value="hat" />Hat</label>
<label><input name="Acc" type="checkbox" value="helmet" />Helmet</label>
<label><input name="Acc" type="checkbox" value="glasses" />Glasses</label>
<br /><br />

<span class="form_col">Pet :</span>
<label><input name="pet" type="radio" value="mount" />Mount</label>
<label><input name="pet" type="radio" value="pet" />Pet</label>
<label><input name="pet" type="radio" value="none" />None</label>
<br /><br />

<span class="form_col"></span>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

your target.php

```
  <?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
        $con = mysqli_connect('servername','username','password','databasename');

    $v_sex = $_POST['sex'];
    $v_race = $_POST['race'];
    $v_prcolor = $_POST['prcolor'];
    $v_bcolor = $_POST['bcolor'];
    $v_hair = $_POST['hair'];
    $v_weapon = $_POST['weapon'];
    $v_clothes = $_POST['clothes'];
    $v_Acc = $_POST['Acc'];
    $_pet = $_POST['pet']; 

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"insert into table_name(sex,race,prcolor,bcolor,hair,weapon,clothes,Acc,pet) values ('$v_sex','$v_race','$v_prcolor','$v_bcolor','$v_hair','$v_weapon','$v_clothes','$v_Acc','$v_pet');

   echo "Data saved successfully!";

}
?>
```

Your table like :

```
Table Name :  Table1        

Fields Name :

sex      varchar(10),
race     varchar(20),
prcolor  varchar(20),
bcolor   varchar(20),
hair     varchar(20),
weapon   varchar(20),
clothes  varchar(20),
Acc      varchar(20),
pet      varchar(20)
```